# Save a VertexPositionColor[] as a Texture 2d

Tags: c#, xna, drawing, primitive, texture2d

I"m currently working on a 2D game that sometimes draws objects using

```cs
GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.LineList, 
                                                       s.edges, 0, 1);
```

or otherwise uses `SpriteBatch`. What I'd like to do is convert a `VertexPoisitonColor[]` into a `Texture2D`, so that an object can start being drawn that way.

My intent is to create an animation that shows the object being drawn, one line at a time, as if by pencil. As my code is now, I can do this, but I'd like to avoid drawing all those primitives every frame once the drawing is finished: I think that might be too slow.

Comment: I am currently working to solve this using a render target, although I feel a better answer exists.

Comment: You only think that it might be slow, or did you actually test and it was slow? Really, try it, you might be surprised.

Comment: I will test it, but first I need to be able to save those same lines as Texture2d's.